# Transaction lock only affecting one user

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a system which I maintain for my work, and I have a report from a user about getting a transaction lock.  It is only this user that reports this out of hundreds, and when she gets the lock, there are other people sitting beside her who are working just fine, and they are able to do the piece work she was just trying to do without the error she is getting.

She's tried wiping her PC, and moving to a difference one, but to no avail, and sometimes the time period for which she will get these lock errors will last up to half an hour.

I was able to find out some information on SQL Server about the lock, like which processes are locking - there's a background job that processes data from another system which runs every 3 minutes, and the conflicting actions she takes on her end produce a select statement, so the update statement is winning the lock every time.  This background job isn't processing a whole lot of information, and the product of the job is an insert or update.

Can anyone suggest why this might be happening, what could cause something like this?  If needed, I can provide more information if you think it would be helpful.  I just don't get it, I would understand if it was happening to lots of people, but it doesn't, only this one user.

**EDIT**:  Maybe it does happen to other users but she's the only one that reports it?  This is the only possible answer I can think of.  The communication with the DB comes from the same web server which everyone is using, so it's practically impossible for an issue like this to happen to only one person.  This is the only thing I can think of.

But if it is happening to everyone, how can I stop transaction locks from occurring as frequently?

Comment: So is the `SELECT` statement they are running a long-running query (so it's taking more than 3 minutes, so the `UPDATE` is occurring)? Are the queries that the other users using less long-running? If so, sounds like the problem is performance based and perhaps the query needs improving to be quicker.

Comment: No, they're all running the same queries, and none of them should take more than a couple of seconds.  See my edit above.  The update/update statement is quite straightforward also, though maybe around 30-40 would run, one after another, at a time.